# How to get the from action of submit button to server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page which contains a submit button and when clicked it was set to an action in the form tag so redirecting to that page

```
<form method="post" action="say google.com">
  <label class="desc" style="color: #333333;">Name:</label>
  <input name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now what I want is that I even want to fire the event in the server side on the submit button click and retain the name value of input tag.

Can anyone help me, please?

**Edit**

I'm working in an aspx page with the form tag having an action to url on the submit button click.This is working fine, but now I want to fire an event on the server side of my page on the submit button click.

Comment: use ajax in that case

Comment: an example pls @RJ

Comment: can you explain your question more. where you want to access that input field value ?.if on submit you are redirecting to `google.com` then handle goes to google.com..we cant modify google.com

Comment: I have edited it my question @RJ. I want to handle the click event on my server side page

Comment: i answered on your question. please check.you can redirect after successful Ajax request to `google.com` in success function.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

**Html :**

```
<form method="post" action="#123">
  <label class="desc" style="color: #333333;">Name:</label>
  <input name="name" id="name"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

**Script :**

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    $.ajax({
     url: "data.php", // server-side page
     data: "name =" +name, // input field value
     success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        location.href = "https://google.com"
    }});
});
```

Event capture is working fine :

[image]

You can redirect after successful Ajax request to `google.com` in success function. Thanks

Comment: it's according your requirement ?..what error you getting ?

Comment: The event itself not firing

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik, event is firing properly. you can check the image attached in answer.

Comment: Can I have the fiddle

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to save that fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){$('#submitForAction').click(function(){$("#submitForAction").submit();});});


Name:

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitForAction"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you work with .aspx page then the form looks like this in browser:

```
<form method="post" action="myPage.aspx">
  <label class="desc" style="color: #333333;">Name:</label>
  <input name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

in Visual Studio you have

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName">Name:</asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" />
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" onClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</form>
```

add

```
<script>
   function redirPost(){
     document.forms[0].action="say googgle.com";
     document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

Notice there is no method and action attributes in the form tag (defaults are POST and your page URL) and no type in asp:button (default is submit)

In the code behind (suppose C#)

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
//do whatever you want with txtName.Text
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redir", "redirPost();", true);
}
```